# Using Symfony @ParamConverter to pass an associative array of objects as parameter

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony @ParamConverter in my controller to pass on an array of objects. I can successfully pass the array of objects using the following config:

```
* @ParamConverter("arrayOfObjects", class="array<MyService\MyClass>", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
```

What I'm getting inside the controller is the following:

```
arrayOfObjects = [
    [0] => {MyService\MyClass}[3],
    [1] => {MyService\MyClass}[3],
    [2] => {MyService\MyClass}[3]
]
...
```

However, the POST call I'm creating uses the following body:

```
{
    "id_1": {
        "name": "name 1",
        "description": "desc 1",
        "number": "number 1",
    },
    "id_2": {
        "name": "name 2",
        "description": "desc 2",
        "number": "number 2",
    },
...
}
```

Now, what I ideally want is for the @ParamConverter to convert the body to something like:

```
arrayOfObjects = [
    ["id_1"] => {MyService\MyClass}[3],
    ["id_2"] => {MyService\MyClass}[3],
    ["id_3"] => {MyService\MyClass}[3]
]
```

Could you see a way to make this work?

My controller:

```
    /**
     * @OA\Post(
     *     path="/post-my-class",
     *     @OA\RequestBody(
     *          required=true,
     *          @OA\JsonContent(
     *               ref="#/components/schemas/MyClass"
     *          )
     *     )
     *)
     * @ParamConverter("arrayOfObjects", class="array<MyService\MyClass>", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     *
     * @Route("/post-my-class", methods="POST")
     * @param MyClass[] $arrayOfObjects
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postController(array $arrayOfObjects): Response
    {
       // Some logic ...
    }
```

My class:

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @OA\Property(
     *     type = "string",
     *     property="name"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type(name="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @OA\Property(
     *     type = "string",
     *     property="description"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type(name="string")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @OA\Property(
     *     type = "string",
     *     property="number"
     * )
     * @Serializer\Type(name="string")
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * MyClass constructor.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $description
     * @param string $number
     */
    public function __construct(
        string $name,
        string $description,
        string $number
    ) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->number = $number;
    }
...
}
```

**Note**: If I use

```
 * @ParamConverter("arrayOfObjects", class="array", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 *
 * @Route("/post-my-class", methods="POST")
 * @param array $arrayOfObjects
```

I get:

```
arrayOfObjects = [
    ["id_1"] => {array}[3],
    ["id_2"] => {array}[3],
    ["id_3"] => {array}[3]
]
```

which is close to what I want but the input parameter isn't converted to a MyClass object but a normal array.

Comment: Why do you need keys? "id_1" "id_2" etc?

Comment: This is how the request is made. I have no influence on that. I need them in order to distinguish between the objects based on their `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get it. The body of the request within the method itself?

```
   /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     */
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        $contentJson=$request->getContent();
        $data=json_decode($contentJson,true);}
```

Comment: This is a valid workaround but I would prefer the way I'm describing it if it's possible.